# Segmentation fault in C <curses.h>

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ncurses, curses

I am very new in coding, so dont be very critical, if I made a simple mistake... I am self-taught, so you are the only one I can ask. Thanks to everyone who will help!

I am trying to make something like "space shooter" with <curses.h>, but it always write me the segmentation fault and I don't understand why. I think I can give you all my code, so you can understand the logic of game, but I think my problem may be from the beginning of curses initialization to the end of it... Maybe I missed refresh() or something like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int sizey = 23;
    int sizex = 40;
    int x, y, yi;
    char world[sizey][sizex];
    char player = 'A';
    char playerLaser = '^';
    char enemy = 'M';
    char enemyShielded = 'O';
    char enemyLaser = 'U';
    char explosion = 'X';
    int score = 0;
    int victory = 1;
    int laserReady = 1;
    int enemyReady = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    /*welcome screen*/
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr,TRUE); 
    printf("\n \n     Welcome soldier! \n \n \n \n");
    usleep(1*100000);
    printf("  Brave the COMMAND PROMPT INVADERS and come back a hero. \n \n \n \n");
    usleep(1*10000);
    printf("  Your operating system is depending upon you. \n \n \n \n");
    usleep(1*10000);
    printf("               Good luck.");
    usleep(1*10000);
    printf("\n \n \n \n Press any key to start.");
    getch();
    /*initialise world*/
    int totalEnemies = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
        for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
            if ((y+1) % 2 == 0 && y < 7 && x > 4
                && x < sizex - 5 && x % 2 ==0) {
                world[y][x] = enemy;
                totalEnemies ++;
            }
            else if ((y+1) % 2 == 0 && y >= 7 && y < 9 && x > 4
                     && x < sizex - 5 && x % 2 ==0){
                world[y][x] = enemyShielded;
                totalEnemies = totalEnemies + 2;
            }
            else {
                world[y][x] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    world[sizey - 1][sizex / 2] = player;
    int i = 1;
    char direction = 'l';
    int currentEnemies = totalEnemies;
    while(currentEnemies > 0 && victory) {
        int drop = 0;
        int enemySpeed = 1 + 10 * currentEnemies / totalEnemies;
        laserReady ++;
        refresh();
        endwin();

        /*display world*/
        system("clear");
        printf("     SCORE:    %d", score);
        printf("\n");
        for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
            printf("|");
            for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
                printf("%c",world[y][x]);
            }
            printf("|");
            printf("\n");
        }
        /*laser time*/
        for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
            for (y = sizey-1; y >= 0; y --) {
                if (i%2 == 0 && world[y][x] == enemyLaser
                    && (world[y+1][x] != enemy & world[y+1][x] != enemyShielded)){
                    world[y+1][x] = enemyLaser;
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                }
                else if (i%2 == 0 && world[y][x] == enemyLaser
                         && (world[y+1][x] == enemy | world[y+1][x] == enemyShielded)){
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
            for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
                if ((i % 5) == 0 && (world[y][x] == enemyShielded
                                     | world[y][x] == enemy) && (rand() % 15) > 13
                    && world[y+1][x] != playerLaser) {
                    for (yi = y+1; yi < sizey; yi ++) {
                        if (world[yi][x] == enemy
                            | world[yi][x] == enemyShielded) {
                            enemyReady = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        enemyReady = 1;
                    }
                    if (enemyReady) {
                        world[y+1][x] = enemyLaser;
                    }
                }
                if (world[y][x] == playerLaser && world[y-1][x] == enemy) {
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                    world[y-1][x] = explosion;
                    currentEnemies --;
                    score = score + 50;
                }
                else if (world[y][x] == playerLaser
                         && world[y-1][x] == enemyShielded) {
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                    world[y-1][x] = enemy;
                    currentEnemies --;
                    score = score + 50;
                }
                else if (world[y][x] == playerLaser
                         && world[y-1][x] == enemyLaser) {
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                }
                else if (world[y][x] == explosion) {
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                }
                else if ((i+1) % 2 == 0 && world[y][x] == enemyLaser
                         && world[y+1][x] == player) {
                    world[y+1][x] = explosion;
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                    victory = 0;
                }
                else if (world[y][x] == playerLaser
                         && world[y-1][x] != enemyLaser) {
                    world[y][x] = ' ';
                    world[y-1][x] = playerLaser;
                }
            }
        }

        /*update enemy direction*/
        for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
            if (world[y][0] == enemy) {
                direction = 'r';
                drop = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (world[y][sizex-1] == enemy){
                direction = 'l';
                drop = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        /*update board*/
        if (i % enemySpeed == 0) {
            if (direction == 'l') {
                for (x = 0; x < sizex - 1; x ++) {
                    for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
                        if (drop && (world[y-1][x+1] == enemy
                                     || world[y-1][x+1] == enemyShielded)){
                            world[y][x] = world[y-1][x+1];
                            world[y-1][x+1] = ' ';
                        }
                        else if (!drop && (world[y][x+1] == enemy
                                           || world[y][x+1] == enemyShielded)) {
                            world[y][x] = world[y][x+1];
                            world[y][x+1] = ' ';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (x = sizex; x > 0; x --) {
                    for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
                        if (drop && (world[y-1][x-1] == enemy
                                     || world[y-1][x-1] == enemyShielded)) {
                            world[y][x] = world[y-1][x-1];
                            world[y-1][x-1] = ' ';
                        }
                        else if (!drop && (world[y][x-1] == enemy
                                           || world[y][x-1] == enemyShielded)) {
                            world[y][x] = world[y][x-1];
                            world[y][x-1] = ' ';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
                if (world[sizey - 1][x] == enemy) {
                    victory = 0;
                }
            }
        }

/*control player*/
        int ch;
        ch = getch();
        if(ch == 'a'){
            for (x = 0; x < sizex; x = x+1) {
                if ( world[sizey-1][x+1] == player) {
                    world[sizey-1][x] = player;
                    world[sizey-1][x+1] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }

        if(ch == 'd'){
            for (x = sizex - 1; x > 0; x = x-1) {
                if ( world[sizey-1][x-1] == player) {
                    world[sizey-1][x] = player;
                    world[sizey-1][x-1] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        if(ch == 'm'&& laserReady > 2){
            for (x = 0; x < sizex; x = x+1) {
                if ( world[sizey-1][x] == player) {
                    world[sizey - 2][x] = playerLaser;
                    laserReady = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        i ++;
        usleep(1*100000);
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("     SCORE:    %d", score);
    printf("\n");
    for (y = 0; y < sizey; y ++) {
        printf("|");
        for (x = 0; x < sizex; x ++) {
            printf("%c",world[y][x]);
        }
        printf("|");
        printf("\n");
    }
    usleep(1*100000);
    system("clear");
    if (victory != 0) {
        printf("\n \n \n \n \n \n               CONGRATULATIONS! \n \n \n \n \n");
        usleep(1*100000);
        printf("\n \n               Score: %d", score);
        usleep(1*100000);
        int bonus = totalEnemies*20 - i;
        printf("\n \n               Bonus: %d", bonus);
        usleep(1*100000);
        printf("\n \n               Total Score: %d", score + bonus);
        printf("\n \n \n \n               Well done");
        usleep(1*100000);
        printf(", Hero.");
        usleep(1*100000);
        getch();
    }
    else {
        printf("\n \n \n \n \n \n               You have failed.");
        usleep(1*100000);
        printf("\n \n \n \n \n \n               Windows is doomed.");
        usleep(1*100000);
        printf("\n \n               Final Score: %d", score);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the segfault happening on? Use a debugger to determine this.

Comment: If you don't use any pointers or dynamic memory allocation, this is probably due to writing outside an array. Check all your array indexes to make sure they're in bounds.

Comment: valgrind https://valgrind.org/ is a good tool for diagnosing memory access bugs (e.g. out-of-bound accesses and memory leaks). And it's easy to use - just install / build it, and supply the original command you used to launch your application altogether as the argument to valgrind. Your program will run much slower because valgrind is examining every single memory access, but it will give you a report in the end of all the memory bugs you made. However it does not run on Windows...

Comment: `world[y+1]` will be out of bounds if you get there when `y == size-1` and `world[y-1]` is out of bounds when `y == 0`. Also, are you meaning to use bitwise AND `&` instead of logical AND `&&`? If so, use parenthesis to disambiguate like the warnings suggest: https://godbolt.org/z/rK8W9qocn

Comment: @Barmar I have the same code without <curses.h> and everything is fine with it, that's why I decided that the problem is in the curses initialization

Comment: Just because you don't get an error doesn't mean it's fine. You may just not be doing anything that stumbles over the corruption it causes. The results of undefined behavior can be anything, including the appearance of correctness.

Answer (score 2):

As was said in the comments above: This is not a curses issue. Rather, there are multiple cases where you try to access elements outside of the world[][] array, and this is what causes the segfaults. I haven't gone through every instance, but for example, consider the "control player" section. In the "a" (left) handler, you correctly range over the cells from 0 up to (but not including) sizex... and then (sometimes) modify the cell at offset sizex, which is out of bounds.

You can rewrite this section in a way that's bounds-safe, and incidentally more efficient:

```
int playerx = sizex / 2;  /* at main() start -- track the player's
                             position instead of looking through the
                             line to find it each time */
...

/* control player */
int ch;
ch = getch();

if (ch == 'a' && playerx > 0) {
    playerx--;
    world[sizey - 1][playerx] = player;
    world[sizey - 1][playerx + 1] = ' ';
}

if (ch == 'd' && playerx < sizex - 1) {
    playerx++;
    world[sizey - 1][playerx] = player;
    world[sizey - 1][playerx - 1] = ' ';
}

if (ch == 'm' && laserReady > 2) {
    world[sizey - 2][playerx] = playerLaser;
    laserReady = 0;
}
```

Note this is just one place where bounds need to be checked.

Meanwhile, since this *is* tagged curses... note that the whole program can be converted to curses pretty easily:

1. Change all instances of `printf()` to `printw()`.
2. Change all instances of `system(clear)` to `erase()`.
3. Change `usleep()` to `napms()` (divide by 1000).
4. Move `endwin()` to the end.
5. Move `nodelay()` after the first `getch()`.
6. Add a `nodelay(stdscr, FALSE)` after the last `erase()`.

Further tweaks will make it work better.